# How to group valuis in ag-Grid component

Tags: ag-grid-react

#### How to group values in ag-Grid component?

I'm working with the ag-Grid component in my project and I'm trying to group some values.

I have defined the columns as follows:

```
field: "vehiclePlate",
          headerName: lan.plate,
          filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
          filterParams: {
            inRangeInclusive: true,
          },
          rowGroup: true,
          hide: true,

    children: [
      {
        field: "driverName",
        headerName: lan.name,
        filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
        filterParams: {
          inRangeInclusive: true,
        },
        rowGroup: true,
        hide: true,
      },

          field: "kmVelocidadMedia",
          headerName: lan.averageSpeed,
          //valueFormatter: roundDecimals,
          valueFormatter: formatNumberToKmH,
          aggFunc: "max",
```

The problem is that if I aggregate by a single column, e.g. number plate, the aggregation operations are performed.

[image]

Sin embargo si agrupo por dos campos, no hace la agregación, además en el nombre de la cabecera tampoco aparece la operación que realiza

[image]

Thanks. Best Regards.

Gruop by many fields